# How to duplicate an object without duplicating animation data?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

What is the easiest way to duplicate an object without it duplicating the animation as well?

I thought I could simply change this in the *user preferences* by unchecking "action" but this doesn't seem to work.  It is of course possible after duplicating to <kbd>U</kbd>*> make single user > animation* then delete keyframes manually, but I'd prefer not to have to do that.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know how to do such duplication without involving Python scripting. If you're concerned about removing action from a large amount of objects quickly, though, you could use this:

Select all objects you want to remove action from, ending with any other object *without any action attached* as the active/last selected object. Then execute **Object** > **Make Links** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>), and select **Animation Data**. It will copy the action from active object, which is `None`, to every other selected objects, effectively removing *their* animation data.

Not exactly what you're looking for, but worth considering as an alternative solution.

Comment: that's a great workaround:)

Comment: you can delete animation data from Outliner